# Linux - how does the kill -k switch work in timeout command

Tags: linux, bash

I have two one liners:

In first. I've expected killing `sh -c "..."` command after 5 seconds but it exists until the timeout exits (for 10 seconds)

```
timeout -k 5s 10s sh -c 'sleep 20s && echo "Long running command which is visible under: ps -elf | grep sleep during whole life (10s) time of timeout command"'
```

In second. I've expected that timeout will exit with return code 124 (because the `sh -c "..."` command is still running) while the command `sh -c "..."` will continue to run (because of kill option for timeout was not set)

```
timeout 10s sh -c 'sleep 20s && echo "Long running command which is visible under: ps -elf | grep sleep during whole life (10s) time of timeout command"'
```

It seems that argument passed to timeout runs for exact time as timeout command itself (it is not killed earlier nor survive timeout) what is the purpose of kill option then?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The option `-k` is to send `KILL` signal after the specified seconds if the process couldn't be terminated after the timeout.

`timeout` first sends the `TERM` signal. If `-k` is specified, then it'll also send `KILL` signal, following the real timeout value.

For example

```
timeout -k 5 10 someCommand
```

`timeout` sends `TERM` signal after the 10 seconds. If `someCommand` didn't respond to `TERM` (e.g. it could block the `TERM` signal) then `timeout` sends `KILL` signal *after* 5 more seconds (i.e. at the 15th second since the start of execution). The signal `KILL` can't be blocked.

Comment: So the whole issue with my one liners is that they are not terminated after TERM signal? Also is possible for process started via timeout to survive timeout?

Comment: Your oneliner will get terminated after 10 seconds (I don't see anything there that would block `TERM`). That's the timeout you specified.  Yes, possible. e.g. if `TERM` is blocked then process will survive.

Comment: Hello Blue Moon, I've tried following command `time timeout -k 5 10 sh -c 'sleep 20s && sighand () { true; }; trap sighand TERM; echo "RUNNING COMMAND"'` which is ignoring the TERM signal but the command runs for 10 seconds not 15

Comment: Seems that sigtrap's argument must be standalone script to test my above example.

Comment: `-k 5 10` I thought it would mean it tries to kill it after 5 seconds and waits 10 more seconds before forcing kill it, but from the above answer I understand it is the other way around. Which one is it ?

Comment: @adrianTNT It's as stated in the answer (and explained in the last paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner to demonstrate how the -k switch works.

```
time timeout -k 5 10 bash -c 'trap "echo -n \"Trapped \"" SIGTERM; for x in {1..20}; do echo -n "$x "; sleep 1; done; echo'
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Terminated
Trapped 11 12 13 14 15 Killed

real    0m15.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```